# Conditional and joint probability manipulations when there are 3 variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having trouble verifying why the following is correct.

$$p(x, y \mid z)= p(x \mid y, z) p(y \mid z)$$

I tried grouping the $(x, y)$ together and split by the conditional, which gives me

$$p(x, y \mid z) = p(z\mid x, y) p(x, y)/p(z)$$

However, this did not bring me any closer. I'm uncertain about what kind of manipulations are allowed given more than 2 variables.

Say an expression like:

$$p(a, b, c)$$

Then I know from the chain rule that I can break it down to:

$$p(a, b, c)=p(a \mid b, c) p(b, c) = p(a \mid b, c) p(b \mid c) p(c)$$

Is it allowed to split by the second comma:

$$p(a, b, c) = p(a, b \mid c) p(c) ?$$

And even more complicated and expression like:
$$p(a|b,c)$$

Am I allowed to rewrite this expression by grouping (a|b) together to give me something like
$$p(a|b,c)=p((a|b)|c)p(c)$$
And does this expression even make sense?

Comment: Some people object to $p((a|b)|c)$. See [this for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92385/multiple-conditioning-on-event-probabilities)

Comment: Actually $a$, $b$ and $c$ should refer to events rather than variables. $p(x,y|z)$ should be written as $P(x\bigcap y| z)$, etc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

$\Pr(a,b,c)=\Pr(a,b\mid c)\Pr(c)$ is allowed.

You are simply saying $\Pr(d,c)=\Pr(d\mid c)\Pr(c)$ where $d = a \cap b$.

Combine this with $\Pr(a,b,c)=\Pr(a\mid b,c)\Pr(b,c)=\Pr(a\mid b,c)\Pr(b\mid c)\Pr(c)$ and divide through by nonzero $\Pr(c)$ to get $\Pr(a,b\mid c)=\Pr(a\mid b,c)\Pr(b\mid c)$.

Comment: Thanks, I had failed to see the obvious $p(a,b,c)/p(c)=p(a,b|c)$